# Detect if a browser can display a pdf inline

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

How can I make sure a browser is capable of displaying a pdf inline?
I used to check the navigator mime type like this:

```
if (navigator && navigator.mimeTypes && navigator.mimeTypes['application/pdf'])
```

However this fails in Firefox 52. For my use case I don't need to know this before the pdf file is loaded, so maybe I can check for content inside the embed tag or something similar?

Comment: See this discussion https://github.com/pipwerks/PDFObject/issues/93 and the linked Firefox bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be a tad late to the party, but I had the same problem and stumbled upon this:

> #### [§ 8.9.1.6 PDF viewing support](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/system-state.html#pdf-viewing-support)
>
> ##### `window.navigator.pdfViewerEnabled`
>
> Returns `true` if the user agent supports inline viewing of PDF files when
> navigating to them, or `false` otherwise. In the latter case, PDF files
> will be handled by external software.

#### Browser compatibility table

After [MDN web docs article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/pdfViewerEnabled):
[image: Support table]

Answer (score 0):

Even later to the party.  Apparently Safari and Safari on IOS will now return true as well.  So, there might not be much point to this any more for anyone using any modern browser.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing a browser is PDF capable does not confirm that the independent frame is visible to a client.

[image]

This Mozilla browser has the choice of using a 3rd party add-in like Acrobat etc, but there is none at present so results are highly unknown.
[image]